# Android AutoCompleteTextView CursorAdapter Fails if using custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview, android-cursoradapter

I have a AutoCompleteTextView and got a CursorAdapter. Now everything works fine you use it with `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line`, but the moment you try to inflate a custom layout Android gives up.

**Works**

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
  final String text = convertToString(cursor);
  ((TextView) view).setText(text);
}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
  final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  final View view =
          inflater.inflate(
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                  parent, false);

 return view;
}
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
@Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      final String text = convertToString(cursor);

      ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAutoCompleteText)).setText(text);
  }


  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
      final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      final View view =
              inflater.inflate(
                        //android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                      R.layout.auto_complete_item,
                      parent, false);

     return view;
  }
```

I Know someone has already asked similar question and was marked as answered, however it does not satisfy my query.

Is there anything I am missing or this is just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Show us your auto_complete_item.xml and your cursor adapter and call to db to get the cursor.

It seems likely that you did not pick the correct default resource id for the text within your auto_complete_item.xml, i.e., "@android:id/list" so the system does not know how to get the text field to fill in your auto_complete_item